# S3 Unload command (python3.x wrapper) hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a process pulling from a huge `Redshift` table that has 4 billion+ rows.  I'm trying to unload into an `S3` bucket, and then copy back up to another table.  Problem is, it sits and churns for 3 hours or so, and then fails.  The weird thing is that when I look in the bucket, I can see 59 slices and a manifest file.  But it doesn't place them there until the process dies (last time I think the error that I got was that the server had closed unexpectedly or something).  Is there a way to optimize this sort of transaction, or is there a better way to perform this type of unload/copy?  I'm wondering why the process sits and hangs, but then shows that it uploaded the files to s3 hours ago when I look at the timestamps in my bucket.  Do I need some kind of code to auto-kill it after a certain period?  Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging

import boto3
import psycopg2 as ppg2

from inst_utils import aws
from inst_config import config3

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Unload step
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    month = timestamp.month
    year = timestamp.year

    s3_sesh = boto3.session.Session(**config3.S3_INFO)
    s3 = s3_sesh.resource('s3')
    fname = 'load_{}_{:02d}'.format(year, month)
    bucket_url = ('canvas_logs/agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types/'
                  '{}/'.format(fname))
    unload_url = ('s3://{}/{}'.format(config3.S3_BUCKET, bucket_url))
    s3.Bucket(config3.S3_BUCKET).put_object(Key=bucket_url)
    table_name = 'requests_{}_{:02d}'.format(year, month - 1)
    logging.info('Starting unload.')
    try:
        with ppg2.connect(**config3.REQUESTS_POSTGRES_INFO) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            # TODO add sql the sql folder to clean up this program.
            unload = r'''
            unload ('select
                        user_id
                        ,course_id
                        ,request_month
                        ,user_agent_type
                        ,count(session_id)
                        ,\'DEV\' etl_requests_usage
                        ,CONVERT_TIMEZONE(\'MST\', getdate()) etl_datetime_local
                        ,\'agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types\' etl_transformation_name
                        ,\'N/A\' etl_pdi_version
                        ,\'N/A\' etl_pdi_build_version
                        ,null etl_pdi_hostname
                        ,null etl_pdi_ipaddress
                        ,null etl_checksum_md5
                     from
                          (select distinct
                              user_id
                              ,context_id as course_id
                              ,date_trunc(\'month\', request_timestamp) request_month
                              ,session_id
                              ,case
                              when user_agent like \'%CanvasAPI%\' then \'api\'
                              when user_agent like \'%candroid%\' then \'mobile_app_android\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iCanvas%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                              when user_agent like \'%CanvasKit%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Windows NT%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%MacBook%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPhone%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPod Touch%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iPad%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%iOS%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%CrOS%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Android%\' then \'mobile\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Linux%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Mac OS%\' then \'desktop\'
                              when user_agent like \'%Macintosh%\' then \'desktop\'
                              else \'other_unknown\'
                              end as user_agent_type
                            from {}
                            where context_type = \'Course\')
                            group by
                              user_id
                              ,course_id
                              ,request_month
                              ,user_agent_type')
            to '{}'
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id={};aws_secret_access_key={}'
            manifest
            gzip
            delimiter '|'
            '''.format(
                table_name, unload_url, config3.S3_ACCESS, config3.S3_SECRET)
            cur.execute(unload)
            conn.commit()

    except ppg2.Error as e:
        logging.critical('Error occurred during transaction: {}'.format(e))
        raise Exception('{}'.format(e))

    logging.info('Starting copy process.')
    schema_name = 'ods_canvas_logs'
    table_name = 'agg_canvas_logs_user_agent_types'

    manifest_url = unload_url + 'manifest'
    logging.info('Manifest url: {}'.format(manifest_url))
    load = aws.RedshiftLoad(schema_name,
                            table_name,
                            manifest_url,
                            config3.S3_INFO,
                            config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD,
                            config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO,
                            safe_load=True,
                            truncate=True
                            )
    load.execute()
```

The `RedshiftLoad` object is just a wrapper class that I created to simplify copying files from S3 since it is such a common occurrence at my job.

Comment: Are you copying the data back to the same cluster? Did you try using Create Table As Select (CTAS) instead of UNLOAD and COPY.

Comment: No its a table in a different cluster